# Как написать инвариант цикла в бинарном поиске

Tags: c#, алгоритм, бинарный-поиск

Сколько я не видел материалов по бинарному поиску - все описывают простейшую форму бинарного поиска в таком виде:

```
public int Search(int[] nums, int target)
{
    var left = 0;
    var right = nums.Length - 1;
    
    while (left <= right)
    {
        var mid = left + (right - left)/2;
        
        if(nums[mid] == target)
            return mid;
        
        if(nums[mid] < target)
            left = mid + 1;
        else
            right = mid - 1;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

И я всё время сколько пишу бинарные поиски задумываюсь о том, как мне логически объяснить почему в цикле while стоит условие `left <= right`, а не `left < right`? Каждый раз сижу и задумываюсь, какой знак поставить, а главное -- почему так?

Как ни странно, но нигде нет объяснения, возможно это настолько очевидно, что даже пояснять не надо?  Прямо говоря, мне не очень хочется запоминать этот факт as is, а хочется понять. Есть ли какое-то объяснение, как лучше понять механику работы этого условия?

Comment: А если ширина диапазона равна один элемент - то чему будет равно left и right? Вот тут и появляется интересный момент на котором одно из условий ("неправильное")  не сработает.

Answer (score 2):

В принципе можно использовать строгое неравенство, но в этом случае необходимо проверить после цикла, что элемент `nums[l]` равен `target`.

Пример - массив из двух элементов `[0, 2]`, ищем `target = 1`.

В первой итерации `l = 0`, `r = 1`, `mid = 0`.

Тогда `nums[mid] == 0`, то есть `nums[mid] < target`. Следовательно, `l` становится равным 1. Цикл `while (l<r) { ... }` завершается. Но `l` нельзя вернуть, так как `nums[1] != target`. Поэтому перед выходом надо проверить, что лежит в массиве по индексу 1.

```
public int Search(int[] nums, int target)
{
    // UPDATE добавлена обработка пустого массива
    if (0 == nums.Length) { return -1; }

    var left = 0;
    var right = nums.Length - 1;
    
    while (left < right)
    {
        var mid = left + (right - left)/2;
        
        if(nums[mid] == target)
            return mid;
        
        if(nums[mid] < target)
            left = mid + 1;
        else
            right = mid - 1;
    }

    return (nums[left] == target)? left : -1;
}
```

Comment: Очень неожиданный вариант, я глядел на комментарий nick_n_a и думал, что именно его версию в ответ кто-нибудь впишет. Но чем он мне нравится -- так это тем, что этот вариант пробрасывает логический мостик от простой формы бин.поиска к поиску leftmost/rightmost элемента (следующий шаг: переносим проверку `if(nums[mid] == target) return mid;` за пределы цикла) и это для меня неожиданная, но очень полезная находка, спасибо! Галку в этом вопросе ставить не буду -- всё-таки он основан на мнениях, разным участникам может другая версия понравится.

Comment: +1, но ваш вариант падает на пустом массиве.

Comment: @VladD спасибо )))

Comment: Если уж говорить о бинарном поиске, возможно, имеет смысл возвращать не `-1`, когда элемент не найден, а индекс для вставки, как это делает, например, [`Array.BinarySearch`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.binarysearch?view=net-5.0). При этом инварианты (наподобие `nums[i] <= target` при `i <= left`) начинают становиться важнее.